# <ShippedDate> is continually coming back null, despite there clearly being a value

Tags: xml, xslt

The XSLT i'm using is -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:Extensions="Extensions" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" 
exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:param name="lookupDataObject" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <InboundASNBridge xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://c:\XML%20Schemas\2004R1\2004R1%20WM%20Schemas\InboundASNBridge_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <xsl:for-each select="*/IDOC/E1EDT20">
                <!-- only write record if details exist-->
                    <InboundASN>
                        <ShipmentNbr>
                            <xsl:value-of select="TKNUM"/>
                        </ShipmentNbr>
                        <!-- Added by Ekta for crossref -->
                        <!--<xsl:variable name="varToLocation">
                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(E1EDL20/E1EDL24/WERKS),1,'ToLocation')"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:if test="$varToLocation != 'NA' ">
                            <ToLocation>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varToLocation"/>
                            </ToLocation>
                        </xsl:if>-->
                        <!-- <ToLocation>
                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(E1EDL20/E1EDL24/WERKS),1,'ToLocation')"/>
                        </ToLocation> -->
                        <AsnType/>
                        <BatchCtlNbr>
                            <!-- Get the rightmost 10 characters -->
                            <xsl:variable name="DOCNUM_NODE" select="../EDI_DC40/DOCNUM"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="DOCNUM_LEN" select="string-length($DOCNUM_NODE)"/>
                            <xsl:if test="$DOCNUM_LEN &gt; 10">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($DOCNUM_NODE,$DOCNUM_LEN -9,10)"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$DOCNUM_LEN &lt;= 10">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$DOCNUM_NODE"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </BatchCtlNbr>
                        <CasesShipped>0</CasesShipped>
                        <ASNHeaderFields>
                            <ManifestNbr>
                                <xsl:if test="../E1EDT20/EXTI1">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="../E1EDT20/EXTI1"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </ManifestNbr> 
                            <BillOfLading></BillOfLading>
                            <PONbr></PONbr>
                            <ShipVia></ShipVia>
                            <TrailerNumber></TrailerNumber>
                            <TelephoneNumber></TelephoneNumber>
                            <WhseTransferFlag></WhseTransferFlag>
                            <QcHoldUponReceipt></QcHoldUponReceipt>
                            <ShippedDate>
                                <xsl:if test="../IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDT10[QUALF='499' and VSTZW_BEZ='Due DC Date']/NTANF != '00000000'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="../IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDT10[QUALF='499' and VSTZW_BEZ='Due DC Date']/NTANF"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </ShippedDate>
                            <TotalWeight>0</TotalWeight>
                            <CountryOrigin><xsl:value-of select="(E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/COUNTRY1)"/></CountryOrigin>
                            <!--<xsl:variable name="varShipmentType">
                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','SHIPMENT_TYPE',true(),string(../E1EDT20/SHTYP),1,'ShipmentType')"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <ShipmentType>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$varShipmentType"/>
                            </ShipmentType>-->
                            <Volume>0</Volume>
                            <StatusCode>10</StatusCode>
                            <FirmApptIndicator>40</FirmApptIndicator>
                            <ScheduledAppt></ScheduledAppt>
                            <ASNOriginalType>P</ASNOriginalType>
                            <ASNDetailType></ASNDetailType>
                        </ASNHeaderFields>
                        <ListOfASNDetails>
                            <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20/E1EDL24">
                                <xsl:variable name="current-pos" select="position()"/>                          
                                <ASNDetail>
                                    <SKUDefinition>
                                        <!-- Added by Ekta for crossref -->
                                        <!--<xsl:variable name="varCompany">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),2,'Company')"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:if test="$varCompany != 'NA' ">
                                            <Company>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$varCompany"/>
                                                --><!-- <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),2,'Company')"/> --><!--
                                            </Company>
                                        </xsl:if>-->
                                        <!-- <Company>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),2,'Company')"/>
                                        </Company> -->
                                        <!-- Added by Ekta for crossref -->
                                        <xsl:variable name="varDivision">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),3,'Division')"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:if test="$varDivision != 'NA' ">
                                            <Division>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$varDivision"/>
                                                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),3,'Division')"/> -->
                                            </Division>
                                        </xsl:if>

                                        <!-- <Division>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="java:onCall($lookupDataObject,'SAP','PlantLoc_to_WhseComDiv',true(),string(WERKS),3,'Division')"/>
                                        </Division> -->
                                        <xsl:variable name="varMATNR">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <Season/>
                                        <SeasonYear/>
                                        <Style/>
                                        <StyleSuffix/>
                                        <Color/>
                                        <SizeDesc><xsl:value-of select="substring($varMATNR,1,12)"/></SizeDesc>
                                        <StockPool><xsl:value-of select="(WERKS)"/></StockPool>
                                    </SKUDefinition>
                                    <SequenceNbr>
                                        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="java:namedCounter($lookupDataObject,0)"/> -->    <!-- Added by Ekta -->  
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$current-pos" /> <!-- Added By Ekta -->
                                    </SequenceNbr>
                                    <UnitsShipped>          <!-- added by ekta -->                          
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="number(LFIMG)">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="LFIMG"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </UnitsShipped>
                                    <SubSKUFields>
                                        <BatchNumber/>
                                        <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
                                    </SubSKUFields>
                                    <PONbr>
                            <!-- Get the rightmost 2 characters -->
                                        <xsl:variable name="varRight">
                                            <xsl:variable name="varWERKS" select="WERKS"/>
                                            <xsl:variable name="varLEN" select="string-length($varWERKS)"/>
                                            <xsl:if test="$varLEN &gt; 1">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($varWERKS,$varLEN -1,$varLEN)"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="varRight1">
                                            <xsl:variable name="varBELNR" select="E1EDL43/BELNR"/>
                                            <xsl:variable name="varLEN1" select="string-length($varBELNR)"/>
                                            <xsl:if test="$varLEN1 &gt; 1">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($varBELNR,$varLEN1 -7,$varLEN1)"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="varRight2">
                                            <xsl:variable name="varPOSNR" select="E1EDL43/POSNR"/>
                                            <xsl:variable name="varLEN2" select="string-length($varPOSNR)"/>
                                            <xsl:if test="$varLEN2 &gt; 1">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($varPOSNR,$varLEN2 -4,$varLEN2)"/>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($varRight,1,2),substring($varRight1,1,8),substring($varRight2,1,5))"/>
                                    </PONbr>
                                    <ASNDetailFields>
                                        <QcHoldUponReceipt>N</QcHoldUponReceipt>
                                        <ActionCode>02</ActionCode>
                                        <ProcessImmdNeeds>Y</ProcessImmdNeeds>
                                        <POLineNbr>0</POLineNbr>
                                        <VendorName><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/NAME1)"/></VendorName>
                                        <VendorItemNumber>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/PARTNER_ID,1,10)"/>
                                        </VendorItemNumber>
                                        <VendorAddress1><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/STREET1)"/></VendorAddress1>
                                        <VendorAddress2><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/STREET2)"/></VendorAddress2>
                                        <VendorAddress3><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/STREET2)"/></VendorAddress3>
                                        <VendorCity><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/CITY1)"/></VendorCity>
                                        <VendorCntry><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/COUNTRY1)"/></VendorCntry>
                                        <VendorPhone><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/TELEPHONE1)"/></VendorPhone>
                                        <VendorFax><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/TELEFAX)"/></VendorFax>
                                        <VendorEmail><xsl:value-of select="(../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='LF']/E_MAIL)"/></VendorEmail>
                                        </ASNDetailFields>
                                </ASNDetail>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ListOfASNDetails>
                    </InboundASN>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </InboundASNBridge>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet><!-- Stylus Studio meta-information - (c)1998-2003 Copyright Sonic Software Corporation. All rights reserved.
<metaInformation>
<scenarios/><MapperInfo srcSchemaPath="" srcSchemaRoot="" srcSchemaPathIsRelative="yes" srcSchemaInterpretAsXML="no" destSchemaPath="" destSchemaRoot="" destSchemaPathIsRelative="yes" destSchemaInterpretAsXML="no"/>
</metaInformation>
-->
```

No matter what I do, i cannot get the XSLT to pass the value of 'MATT' through the XSLT as output.

The example XML i'm passing through is -

```
    <?xml
version="1.0"?><SHPMNT05><IDOC
BEGIN="1"><EDI_DC40
SEGMENT="1"><TABNAM><![CDATA[EDI_DC40]]></TABNAM><MANDT>500</MANDT><DOCNUM>0000000581904575</DOCNUM><DOCREL>740</DOCREL><STATUS>03</STATUS><DIRECT>1</DIRECT><OUTMOD>4</OUTMOD><IDOCTYP>SHPMNT05</IDOCTYP><MESTYP>SHPMNT</MESTYP><SNDPOR>SAPPR3</SNDPOR><SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT><SNDPRN>PR3CLNT500</SNDPRN><RCVPOR>EISSHPMNT</RCVPOR><RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT><RCVPFC>LS</RCVPFC><RCVPRN>WESTWAY</RCVPRN><CREDAT>20180614</CREDAT><CRETIM>114718</CRETIM><SERIAL>20180614114714</SERIAL></EDI_DC40><E1EDT20
SEGMENT="1"><TKNUM>0002210124</TKNUM><SHTYP>Z010</SHTYP><ABFER>2</ABFER><ABWST>1</ABWST><BFART>1</BFART><LAUFK>4</LAUFK><ROUTE>GBSTN</ROUTE><EXTI1>ECMU4556130</EXTI1><EXTI2>YAT0005864732</EXTI2><STTRG>1</STTRG><DTMEG>KGM</DTMEG><DTMEV>DMQ</DTMEV><DISTZ>0.000</DISTZ><FAHZT>0.00</FAHZT><GESZT>0.00</GESZT><GESZTD>0</GESZTD><FAHZTD>0</FAHZTD><GESZTDA>0</GESZTDA><FAHZTDA>0</FAHZTDA><WARZTD>
0</WARZTD><WARZTDA>
0</WARZTDA><E1EDT22
SEGMENT="1"><SHTYP_BEZ>01)Westway
Shipment</SHTYP_BEZ><BFART_BEZ>Load</BFART_BEZ><LAUFK_BEZ>Direct
leg</LAUFK_BEZ><ROUTE_BEZ>Southampton -
GF</ROUTE_BEZ><STTRG_BEZ>Planning
completed</STTRG_BEZ></E1EDT22><E1EDT18
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>ORI</QUALF></E1EDT18><E1ADRM4
SEGMENT="1"><PARTNER_Q>OTP</PARTNER_Q><PARTNER_ID>0001</PARTNER_ID><LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE><COUNTRY1>GB</COUNTRY1><E1ADRE4
SEGMENT="1"><EXTEND_Q>305</EXTEND_Q><EXTEND_D>0001</EXTEND_D></E1ADRE4></E1ADRM4><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Loading</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>20180511</NTANF><NTANZ>010000</NTANZ><NTEND>20180511</NTEND><NTENZ>010000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>WSHDR0001</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS LOADING
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Depart Port of
Loadi</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>20180523</NTANF><NTANZ>010000</NTANZ><NTEND>20180523</NTEND><NTENZ>010000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>WSHDR0005</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS ETD
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Arrival Port of
Dest</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>20180617</NTANF><NTANZ>010000</NTANZ><NTEND>20180617</NTEND><NTENZ>010000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>WSHDR0006</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS ETA
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Due DC
Date</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>MATT</NTANF><NTANZ>010000</NTANZ><NTEND>20180622</NTEND><NTENZ>010000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>WSHDR0007</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS DUE DC
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Import
date</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>00000000</NTANF><NTANZ>000000</NTANZ><NTEND>00000000</NTEND><NTENZ>000000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>ZWSHDR0008</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS IMP DT
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Free
date</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>00000000</NTANF><NTANZ>000000</NTANZ><NTEND>00000000</NTEND><NTENZ>000000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>ZWSHDR0009</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS FRE DT
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDT10
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>499</QUALF><VSTZW_BEZ>Release
date</VSTZW_BEZ><NTANF>00000000</NTANF><NTANZ>000000</NTANZ><NTEND>00000000</NTEND><NTENZ>000000</NTENZ><ISDD>00000000</ISDD><ISDZ>000000</ISDZ><IEDD>00000000</IEDD><IEDZ>000000</IEDZ><EVENT>ZWSHDR0010</EVENT><EVENT_ALI>WS REL DT
FREE</EVENT_ALI></E1EDT10><E1EDL35
SEGMENT="1"><STAWN>6404199000</STAWN><EXART>10</EXART><HERKL>CN</HERKL><HERKR>SO</HERKR><GRWRT>696.62</GRWRT><E1EDL36
SEGMENT="1"><EXART_BEZ>Standard Sale or
Purchase</EXART_BEZ><HERKL_BEZ>China</HERKL_BEZ></E1EDL36></E1EDL35><E1EDL43
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>V</QUALF><BELNR>0061025409</BELNR><POSNR>000130</POSNR></E1EDL43><E1EDL24
SEGMENT="1"><POSNR>000080</POSNR><MATNR>261214585040</MATNR><ARKTX>Sillian Bella Navy, E,
4</ARKTX><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><WERKS>DC01</WERKS><LGORT>0001</LGORT><CHARG>00004</CHARG><LFIMG>64.000</LFIMG><VRKME>PCE</VRKME><LGMNG>64.000</LGMNG><MEINS>PCE</MEINS><NTGEW>18.752</NTGEW><BRGEW>18.752</BRGEW><GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI><VOLUM>304.640</VOLUM><VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH><LADGR>Z001</LADGR><TRAGR>0001</TRAGR><GRKOR>000</GRKOR><EAN11>5050406676793</EAN11><POSEX>000004</POSEX><VFDAT>20180511</VFDAT><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT><VGBEL>0061025409</VGBEL><VGPOS>000120</VGPOS><ORMNG>
64.000</ORMNG><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B><E1EDL25
SEGMENT="1"><LGORT_BEZ>Putaway</LGORT_BEZ><LADGR_BEZ>MHE</LADGR_BEZ><TRAGR_BEZ>On
pallets</TRAGR_BEZ></E1EDL25><E1EDL26
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV>ELN</PSTYV><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><UMVKZ>1</UMVKZ><UMVKN>1</UMVKN><UEBTK>X</UEBTK><UEBTO>0.0</UEBTO><UNTTO>5.0</UNTTO><MAGRV>BOX</MAGRV><E1EDL27
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV_BEZ>Inbound
Delivery</PSTYV_BEZ><MATKL_BEZ>W Casual Clks
Shoes</MATKL_BEZ><WERKS_BEZ>Clarks
Retail</WERKS_BEZ></E1EDL27></E1EDL26><E1EDL35
SEGMENT="1"><STAWN>6404199000</STAWN><EXART>10</EXART><HERKL>CN</HERKL><HERKR>SO</HERKR><GRWRT>696.62</GRWRT><E1EDL36
SEGMENT="1"><EXART_BEZ>Standard Sale or
Purchase</EXART_BEZ><HERKL_BEZ>China</HERKL_BEZ></E1EDL36></E1EDL35><E1EDL43
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>V</QUALF><BELNR>0061025409</BELNR><POSNR>000120</POSNR></E1EDL43></E1EDL24><E1EDL24
SEGMENT="1"><POSNR>000090</POSNR><MATNR>261214585035</MATNR><ARKTX>Sillian Bella Navy, E,
3+</ARKTX><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><WERKS>DC01</WERKS><LGORT>0001</LGORT><CHARG>00001</CHARG><LFIMG>16.000</LFIMG><VRKME>PCE</VRKME><LGMNG>16.000</LGMNG><MEINS>PCE</MEINS><NTGEW>4.576</NTGEW><BRGEW>4.576</BRGEW><GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI><VOLUM>76.160</VOLUM><VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH><LADGR>Z001</LADGR><TRAGR>0001</TRAGR><GRKOR>000</GRKOR><EAN11>5050406676786</EAN11><POSEX>000001</POSEX><VFDAT>20180511</VFDAT><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT><VGBEL>0061025409</VGBEL><VGPOS>000110</VGPOS><ORMNG>
16.000</ORMNG><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B><E1EDL25
SEGMENT="1"><LGORT_BEZ>Putaway</LGORT_BEZ><LADGR_BEZ>MHE</LADGR_BEZ><TRAGR_BEZ>On
pallets</TRAGR_BEZ></E1EDL25><E1EDL26
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV>ELN</PSTYV><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><UMVKZ>1</UMVKZ><UMVKN>1</UMVKN><UEBTK>X</UEBTK><UEBTO>0.0</UEBTO><UNTTO>5.0</UNTTO><MAGRV>BOX</MAGRV><E1EDL27
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV_BEZ>Inbound
Delivery</PSTYV_BEZ><MATKL_BEZ>W Casual Clks
Shoes</MATKL_BEZ><WERKS_BEZ>Clarks
Retail</WERKS_BEZ></E1EDL27></E1EDL26><E1EDL35
SEGMENT="1"><STAWN>6404199000</STAWN><EXART>10</EXART><HERKL>CN</HERKL><HERKR>SO</HERKR><GRWRT>174.15</GRWRT><E1EDL36
SEGMENT="1"><EXART_BEZ>Standard Sale or
Purchase</EXART_BEZ><HERKL_BEZ>China</HERKL_BEZ></E1EDL36></E1EDL35><E1EDL43
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>V</QUALF><BELNR>0061025409</BELNR><POSNR>000110</POSNR></E1EDL43></E1EDL24><E1EDL24
SEGMENT="1"><POSNR>000100</POSNR><MATNR>261214584090</MATNR><ARKTX>Sillian Bella Navy, D,
9</ARKTX><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><WERKS>DC01</WERKS><LGORT>0001</LGORT><CHARG>00003</CHARG><LFIMG>36.000</LFIMG><VRKME>PCE</VRKME><LGMNG>36.000</LGMNG><MEINS>PCE</MEINS><NTGEW>13.356</NTGEW><BRGEW>13.356</BRGEW><GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI><VOLUM>253.440</VOLUM><VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH><LADGR>Z001</LADGR><TRAGR>0001</TRAGR><GRKOR>000</GRKOR><EAN11>5050406762489</EAN11><POSEX>000003</POSEX><VFDAT>20180511</VFDAT><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT><VGBEL>0061025409</VGBEL><VGPOS>000100</VGPOS><ORMNG>
36.000</ORMNG><EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B>0</EXPIRY_DATE_EXT_B><E1EDL25
SEGMENT="1"><LGORT_BEZ>Putaway</LGORT_BEZ><LADGR_BEZ>MHE</LADGR_BEZ><TRAGR_BEZ>On
pallets</TRAGR_BEZ></E1EDL25><E1EDL26
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV>ELN</PSTYV><MATKL>MC018</MATKL><UMVKZ>1</UMVKZ><UMVKN>1</UMVKN><UEBTK>X</UEBTK><UEBTO>0.0</UEBTO><UNTTO>5.0</UNTTO><MAGRV>BOX</MAGRV><E1EDL27
SEGMENT="1"><PSTYV_BEZ>Inbound
Delivery</PSTYV_BEZ><MATKL_BEZ>W Casual Clks
Shoes</MATKL_BEZ><WERKS_BEZ>Clarks
Retail</WERKS_BEZ></E1EDL27></E1EDL26><E1EDL35
SEGMENT="1"><STAWN>6404199000</STAWN><EXART>10</EXART><HERKL>CN</HERKL><HERKR>SO</HERKR><GRWRT>391.85</GRWRT><E1EDL36
SEGMENT="1"><EXART_BEZ>Standard Sale or
Purchase</EXART_BEZ><HERKL_BEZ>China</HERKL_BEZ></E1EDL36></E1EDL35><E1EDL43
SEGMENT="1"><QUALF>V</QUALF><BELNR>0061025409</BELNR><POSNR>000100</POSNR></E1EDL43></E1EDL24></E1EDT20><EDI_DS40
SEGMENT="1"><MANDT>500</MANDT><DOCNUM>0000000581904575</DOCNUM><LOGDAT>20180614</LOGDAT><LOGTIM>114718</LOGTIM><STATUS>01</STATUS><STAMNO>000</STAMNO><UNAME>KFOSTER</UNAME><SEGNUM>000000</SEGNUM></EDI_DS40><EDI_DS40
SEGMENT="1"><MANDT>500</MANDT><DOCNUM>0000000581904575</DOCNUM><LOGDAT>20180614</LOGDAT><LOGTIM>114718</LOGTIM><STATUS>30</STATUS><STAMQU>SAP</STAMQU><STAMID>B1</STAMID><STAMNO>006</STAMNO><STATYP>S</STATYP><STAPA1>Receiver
exists</STAPA1><STAPA2>No
filters</STAPA2><STAPA3>No
conversion</STAPA3><STAPA4>No version
change</STAPA4><STATXT><![CDATA[&, &, &,
&]]></STATXT><UNAME>KFOSTER</UNAME><SEGNUM>000000</SEGNUM></EDI_DS40><EDI_DS40
SEGMENT="1"><MANDT>500</MANDT><DOCNUM>0000000581904575</DOCNUM><LOGDAT>20180614</LOGDAT><LOGTIM>115859</LOGTIM><STATUS>03</STATUS><STAMQU>SAP</STAMQU><STAMID>EA</STAMID><STAMNO>095</STAMNO><STATYP>I</STATYP><STAPA1>http://manhattaneis:13029</STAPA1><STAPA4>HTTP Response
Code:200</STAPA4><STATXT>IDoc sent by HTTP in XML
format</STATXT><UNAME>TWSUSER</UNAME><REPID>LEDI7F10</REPID><SEGNUM>000000</SEGNUM></EDI_DS40></IDOC></SHPMNT05>
```

And i'm wondering if i'm using the incorrect path names but i've tried multiple options and it still just passes as a null value.

I've had to pass only part of the example IDOC as it was too big to post in the body of this post, but I could upload this somewhere if required to access?

Is it the 'and' qualifier that's wrong?

Please help i'm losing my mind!

Comment: Please add a ***complete*** [mcve].   Issue may involve a difference between what you think is the context node and what it really is, and we cannot help with that given only what you've posted.

Comment: Shall I pass both full XSLT and full XML example?

Comment: No, you should reduce it to the *minimum* size that's still *complete* enough to exhibit the problem.  It was good that you reduced it -- you just went a bit too far.  We should be able to run your example and *verify* the issue without having to wade through extraneous code.   (You may even find the problem yourself in the process of creating a MCVE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, try to change it to the following. I changed the XPath of the `xsl:if` and the `xsl:value`. At this point in the XSLT the `current()` node is `E1EDT20` from the for-loop and `E1EDT10` is a direct child of this, so I removed the `../IDOC/E1EDT20/` from the expressions. The second thing to change was to wrap the `VSTZW_BEZ` value in a `normalize-space(...)`
, because its value 'Due DC Date' is split across two lines. Looking at your XML you should make this change a habit.

This is the modified code:

```
<ShippedDate>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:if test="E1EDT10[QUALF='499' and normalize-space(VSTZW_BEZ)='Due DC Date']/NTANF != '00000000'">
        <xsl:value-of select="E1EDT10[QUALF='499' and normalize-space(VSTZW_BEZ)='Due DC Date']/NTANF"/>
    </xsl:if>
</ShippedDate>
```